# GET request with files argument in requests library Python

Tags: python, http, python-requests, get

I find this code and I really don't understand it, how is it possible to send data (not query) with GET request

```
response = requests.get(
            check_all_info_url_2, files=multipart_form_data, timeout=30)
```

and what is `files=` argument in the get request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `requests.get` is just a [wrapper function](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/_modules/requests/api/#get) this will just call `requests.request`.  Unless `requests.session` implementes any checking, it will happily send off a `GET` request with multipart data in it.

Is this valid?  Not to my knowledge, although I'm willing to be proven wrong.  No api I have ever written would accept file upload on a GET request.  But not every server will even check the method, so perhaps this code is interacting with a badly written server which doesn't reject for wrong method, or perhap's it's even interacting with a worse server which expects file upload with GET.  There are lots of broken servers out there ;)

In any case, the reason this works with *requests* is that it just passes keyword arguments through to the underlying session without performing any kind of validation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, I have to connect to this endpoint in this server. Do you know any JavaScript library can do this weird behavior (sending a get request with multipart data).

Comment: I have never tried; you can try the way you normally would (axios/whatever). But also try a proper POST request: the server is more likely to be ignoring the request *type* than actively configured for the wrong request time